# Create new pandas row as a result of combination of text values from different rows which has same value in other pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to create a new pandas data-frame as a result of concatenating text values which has the same value in other column. So for instance, I got the following dataframe:

```
example_dct = {
  "text": {
    "0": "this is my text 1",
    "1": "this is my text 2",
    "2": "this is my text 3",
    "3": "this is my text 4",
    "4": "this is my text 5"
  },
  "article_id": {
    "0": "#0001_01_xml",
    "1": "#0001_01_xml",
    "2": "#0001_02_xml",
    "3": "#0001_03_xml",
    "4": "#0001_03_xml"
  }
}

df_example = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(example_dct) 
print(df_example)

         text           article_id
0  this is my text 1  #0001_01_xml
1  this is my text 2  #0001_01_xml
2  this is my text 3  #0001_02_xml
3  this is my text 4  #0001_03_xml
4  this is my text 5  #0001_03_xml
```

I would like to concatenate in the following way: text1+'***' +text2

So, in this case idx 0,1 should be concatenated and 3, 4

Hence, the resulted dataframe will be:

```
            text                                article_id
0  'this is my text 1 *** this is my text 2'  #0001_01_xml
1  'this is my text 4 *** this is my text 5'  #0001_03_xml
```

In the case that there is >2 text values with the same id value, example:

```
example_dct = {
  "text": {
    "0": "this is my text 1",
    "1": "this is my text 2",
    "2": "this is my text 3",
    "3": "this is my text 4",
    "4": "this is my text 5",
    "5": "this is my text 6",
  },
  "article_id": {
    "0": "#0001_01_xml",
    "1": "#0001_01_xml",
    "2": "#0001_02_xml",
    "3": "#0001_03_xml",
    "4": "#0001_03_xml", 
    "5": "#0001_03_xml",
  }
}
```

Then the output dataframe should be the result of concatenating 1 by 1 texts:

```
            text                                article_id
0  'this is my text 1 *** this is my text 2'  #0001_01_xml
1  'this is my text 4 *** this is my text 5'  #0001_03_xml
2  'this is my text 4 *** this is my text 6'  #0001_03_xml
3  'this is my text 5 *** this is my text 6'  #0001_03_xml
```

I have been trying to apply some groupby queries, concatenating all the texts with the same column value, i.e. `df.groupby('article_id', sort=False)['text'].apply('***'.join)`
creating just one row, but I would like to create 1by1 rows as described above

Any ideas how can I make this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on `article_id` and use a custom lambda function that produces all possible combinations of `length=2` of strings in `text` columns, finally use [`Series.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) + [`Series.dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html):

```
from itertools import combinations

f = lambda g: [*map(' *** '.join, combinations(g['text'], r=2))]
df = df.groupby('article_id').apply(f).explode().dropna().reset_index(name='text')
```

Result:

```
# example1
     article_id                                     text
0  #0001_01_xml  this is my text 1 *** this is my text 2
1  #0001_03_xml  this is my text 4 *** this is my text 5

# example 2
     article_id                                     text
0  #0001_01_xml  this is my text 1 *** this is my text 2
1  #0001_03_xml  this is my text 4 *** this is my text 5
2  #0001_03_xml  this is my text 4 *** this is my text 6
3  #0001_03_xml  this is my text 5 *** this is my text 6
```

Comment: works perfect!!! combinations works amazing!! didn't know it exist before. Also, how could you randomly join texts that do not belong to the same article_id? text:  this is my text 1 *** this is my text 6, article_id-> 'different_ids'

Comment: @sanchezjAI If wants to join the text that belongs to different ids simply dont use groupby and just map the lambda function on the entire text column, like `f(df)` to get the all possible combinations.

Comment: but then if I write: df_NONconnected = df_info_annotated.apply(f).explode().dropna()
df_NONconnected.info() I get an error:  KeyError: ('text', 'occurred at index text')

Comment: @sanchezjAI Lets discuss [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219688/ds8)

Comment: Could you check this one @shubhamsharma ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63597577/how-to-add-two-columns-of-values-from-grouping-two-by-two-values-from-another-co

Comment: @sanchezjAI Sure give me a sec.