# How to add two columns of values from grouping two by two values from another column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I would like to create a new pandas data-frame as a result of grouping text values which has the same value in other column. So for instance, I got the following dataframe:

```
example_dct = {
  "text": {
    "0": "this is my text 1",
    "1": "this is my text 2",
    "2": "this is my text 3",
    "3": "this is my text 4",
    "4": "this is my text 5"
  },
  "article_id": {
    "0": "#0001_01_xml",
    "1": "#0001_01_xml",
    "2": "#0001_02_xml",
    "3": "#0001_03_xml",
    "4": "#0001_03_xml"
  }
}

df_example = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(example_dct) 
print(df_example)

         text           article_id
0  this is my text 1  #0001_01_xml
1  this is my text 2  #0001_01_xml
2  this is my text 3  #0001_02_xml
3  this is my text 4  #0001_03_xml
4  this is my text 5  #0001_03_xml
```

I would like to create two new columns in the following way:

```
            text_1               text_2                 article_id
0  'this is my text 1'     'this is my text 2'            #0001_01_xml
1  'this is my text 4'     'this is my text 5'            #0001_03_xml
```

In the case that there is >2 text values with the same id value, example:

```
example_dct = {
  "text": {
    "0": "this is my text 1",
    "1": "this is my text 2",
    "2": "this is my text 3",
    "3": "this is my text 4",
    "4": "this is my text 5",
    "5": "this is my text 6",
  },
  "article_id": {
    "0": "#0001_01_xml",
    "1": "#0001_01_xml",
    "2": "#0001_02_xml",
    "3": "#0001_03_xml",
    "4": "#0001_03_xml", 
    "5": "#0001_03_xml",
  }
}
```

Then the output dataframe should be the result of concatenating 1 by 1 texts:

```
            text_1               text_2                 article_id
0  'this is my text 1'      'this is my text 2'         #0001_01_xml
1  'this is my text 4'      'this is my text 5'         #0001_03_xml
2  'this is my text 4'      'this is my text 6'         #0001_03_xml
3  'this is my text 5'      'this is my text 6'         #0001_03_xml
```

Furthermore, I would like to create another dataset similar to this one, but just with those columns that does not have common article_id (so the inverse of group by).
Example:

```
            text_1               text_2                 article_id_1     article_id_2
0  'this is my text 1'      'this is my text 3'         #0001_01_xml.       "#0001_02_xml"   
1  'this is my text 1'      'this is my text 4'         #0001_01_xml"       #0001_03_xml"
2  'this is my text 1'      'this is my text 5'         #0001_01_xml.        "#0001_03_xml" 
3  'this is my text 1'      'this is my text 6'         #0001_01_xml        "#0001_03_xml" 
4  'this is my text 2'      'this is my text 3'         #0001_02_xml        "#0001_03_xml"
5  'this is my text 2'      'this is my text 4'         #0001_02_xml        "#0001_03_xml"
6  'this is my text 2'      'this is my text 5'         #0001_02_xml        "#0001_03_xml"
7  'this is my text 2'      'this is my text 6'         #0001_02_xml        "#0001_03_xml"
..
..
..
..
..
```

Any ideas how can I make this approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For first use combinations of 2 values per groups in flattened list compreehnsion, there are groups with 1 values omitted by default:

```
example_dct = {
  "text": {
    "0": "this is my text 1",
    "1": "this is my text 2",
    "2": "this is my text 3",
    "3": "this is my text 4",
    "4": "this is my text 5",
    "5": "this is my text 6",
  },
  "article_id": {
    "0": "#0001_01_xml",
    "1": "#0001_01_xml",
    "2": "#0001_02_xml",
    "3": "#0001_03_xml",
    "4": "#0001_03_xml", 
    "5": "#0001_03_xml",
  }
}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(example_dct)
```

---

```
from  itertools import  combinations

L = [y + (name,) for name, x in df.groupby('article_id')['text'] for y in combinations(x, 2)]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['text_1','text_2', 'article_id'])
print(df1)
              text_1             text_2    article_id
0  this is my text 1  this is my text 2  #0001_01_xml
1  this is my text 4  this is my text 5  #0001_03_xml
2  this is my text 4  this is my text 6  #0001_03_xml
3  this is my text 5  this is my text 6  #0001_03_xml
```

So if changed values `0001_02_xml` to `0001_03_xml` get:

```
example_dct = {
  "text": {
    "0": "this is my text 1",
    "1": "this is my text 2",
    "2": "this is my text 3",
    "3": "this is my text 4",
    "4": "this is my text 5",
    "5": "this is my text 6",
  },
  "article_id": {
    "0": "#0001_01_xml",
    "1": "#0001_01_xml",
    "2": "#0001_03_xml",
    "3": "#0001_03_xml",
    "4": "#0001_03_xml", 
    "5": "#0001_03_xml",
  }
}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(example_dct)
```

---

```
from  itertools import  combinations

L = [y + (name,) for name, x in df.groupby('article_id')['text'] for y in combinations(x, 2)]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['text_1','text_2', 'article_id'])
print(df1)
              text_1             text_2    article_id
0  this is my text 1  this is my text 2  #0001_01_xml
1  this is my text 3  this is my text 4  #0001_03_xml
2  this is my text 3  this is my text 5  #0001_03_xml
3  this is my text 3  this is my text 6  #0001_03_xml
4  this is my text 4  this is my text 5  #0001_03_xml
5  this is my text 4  this is my text 6  #0001_03_xml
6  this is my text 5  this is my text 6  #0001_03_xml
```

For second use:

```
df2 = (df.assign(a=1).merge(df.assign(a=1), on='a', suffixes=('_1','_2'))
         .merge(df1, indicator=True, how='left')
          .query('_merge == "left_only" &  article_id_1 != article_id_2')
          [['text_1','text_2', 'article_id_1','article_id_2']]
         )
print (df2)
               text_1             text_2  article_id_1  article_id_2
2   this is my text 1  this is my text 3  #0001_01_xml  #0001_02_xml
3   this is my text 1  this is my text 4  #0001_01_xml  #0001_03_xml
4   this is my text 1  this is my text 5  #0001_01_xml  #0001_03_xml
5   this is my text 1  this is my text 6  #0001_01_xml  #0001_03_xml
8   this is my text 2  this is my text 3  #0001_01_xml  #0001_02_xml
9   this is my text 2  this is my text 4  #0001_01_xml  #0001_03_xml
10  this is my text 2  this is my text 5  #0001_01_xml  #0001_03_xml
11  this is my text 2  this is my text 6  #0001_01_xml  #0001_03_xml
12  this is my text 3  this is my text 1  #0001_02_xml  #0001_01_xml
13  this is my text 3  this is my text 2  #0001_02_xml  #0001_01_xml
15  this is my text 3  this is my text 4  #0001_02_xml  #0001_03_xml
16  this is my text 3  this is my text 5  #0001_02_xml  #0001_03_xml
17  this is my text 3  this is my text 6  #0001_02_xml  #0001_03_xml
18  this is my text 4  this is my text 1  #0001_03_xml  #0001_01_xml
19  this is my text 4  this is my text 2  #0001_03_xml  #0001_01_xml
20  this is my text 4  this is my text 3  #0001_03_xml  #0001_02_xml
24  this is my text 5  this is my text 1  #0001_03_xml  #0001_01_xml
25  this is my text 5  this is my text 2  #0001_03_xml  #0001_01_xml
26  this is my text 5  this is my text 3  #0001_03_xml  #0001_02_xml
30  this is my text 6  this is my text 1  #0001_03_xml  #0001_01_xml
31  this is my text 6  this is my text 2  #0001_03_xml  #0001_01_xml
32  this is my text 6  this is my text 3  #0001_03_xml  #0001_02_xml
```

Comment: the first df is correct! the second one I would like to get tex_1 and text_2 of those that does not have the same article ID, so #0001_01_xml text with #0001_02_xml (text_1: this is my text 1; text_2: this is my text 3), (text_1: this is my text 1; text_2: this is my text 4), etc. @jezrael

Comment: @sanchezjAI - Can you add expected output of df2 to question, because bad formating in comments?

Comment: I just added the output

Comment: @sanchezjAI - Added solution for second one.

Answer (score 0):

```
example_dct = {
  "text": {
    "0": "this is my text 1",
    "1": "this is my text 2",
    "2": "this is my text 3",
    "3": "this is my text 4",
    "4": "this is my text 5",
    "5": "this is my text 6",
  },
  "article_id": {
    "0": "#0001_01_xml",
    "1": "#0001_01_xml",
    "2": "#0001_02_xml",
    "3": "#0001_03_xml",
    "4": "#0001_03_xml",
    "5": "#0001_03_xml",
  }
}
df_example = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(example_dct)
print(df_example)
                text    article_id
0  this is my text 1  #0001_01_xml
1  this is my text 2  #0001_01_xml
2  this is my text 3  #0001_02_xml
3  this is my text 4  #0001_03_xml
4  this is my text 5  #0001_03_xml
5  this is my text 6  #0001_03_xml

df_example=df_example[
    df_example.duplicated(subset=['article_id'],keep=False)
]
df_example2=df_example

df=df_example.merge(df_example2,on='article_id',how='inner')
df['no_x']=df.text_x.str.extract(r'text (\d+)').astype(float)
df['no_y']=df.text_y.str.extract(r'text (\d+)').astype(float)

df = df[
    df.no_x < df.no_y
]
del df['no_x']
del df['no_y']

print(df)

              text_x    article_id             text_y
1  this is my text 1  #0001_01_xml  this is my text 2
5  this is my text 4  #0001_03_xml  this is my text 5
6  this is my text 4  #0001_03_xml  this is my text 6
9  this is my text 5  #0001_03_xml  this is my text 6
```